# multiple coupon code apply on magento cart

Tags: php, javascript

I have been working for 2 days for applying multiple coupon on cart I know there are modules which are available for that. But i don't want to use it. I want some custom code so that i can apply more than 1 coupon code in the single order.

Comment: What Magento version do you use?  Can you show us the Result (code) of your 2 days. On what step do you have problems. Please be more specific